# Slicing a Python list with a NumPy array of indices -- any fast way?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, optimization

I have a regular `list` called `a`, and a NumPy array of indices `b`.
(No, it is not possible for me to convert `a` to a NumPy array.)

Is there any way for me to the same effect as "`a[b]`" efficiently?  To be clear, this implies that I don't want to extract every individual `int` in `b` due to its performance implications.

(Yes, this is a bottleneck in my code. That's why I'm using NumPy arrays to begin with.)

Comment: I don't know how much faster (if at all) `operator.itemgetter()` would be.

Comment: What is your plan for (what would be) `a[b]`?  It's hard to imagine a use for it that won't "extract an individual `int` for ever integer in `b`"... eventually.  If you're concerned about wasting space having a list and a sublist hanging around simultaneously, it seems that you could iterate (or whatever) over `b` at the time of need, instead of the (would be) `a[b]`.

Comment: @jedwards: My sentence was a little ambiguous (fixed), but what I was say was that I'm trying to avoid extracting the individual elements of `b` (I don't need it and it slows my code down). I'm using the extracted elements of `a` afterward (e.g. looking at which ones are `None`, etc... it's not really relevant) but that hardly implies I need to extract `b`'s elements manually in the process.

Comment: `itemgetter` creates a class instance with a callable.  I think its speed improvement comes from a simpler interpretation or calling stack.  It does not use any special C code (that I can see).  I get, at best, a 2x speed improvement.

Comment: For me (Python3, Numpy 1.10.4) -- `itemgetter` seems the fastest, a list comprehension over `b` being ~56% slower, and a comprehension over `np.nditer(b)` being ~134% slower.

Comment: `nditer` isn't a speed help, even when used for real numpy cases.  It's a stepping stone toward compiled C code (e.g. via Cython).

Answer (score 3):

```
a = list(range(1000000))
b = np.random.randint(0, len(a), 10000)

%timeit np.array(a)[b]
10 loops, best of 3: 84.8 ms per loop

%timeit [a[x] for x in b]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.93 ms per loop

%timeit operator.itemgetter(*b)(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 ms per loop

%timeit np.take(a, b)
10 loops, best of 3: 91.3 ms per loop
```

I had high hopes for `numpy.take()` but it is far from optimal.  I tried some Numba solutions as well, and they yielded similar times--around 92 ms.

So a simple list comprehension is not far from the best here, but `operator.itemgetter()` wins, at least for input sizes at these orders of magnitude.

Comment: This method seems to have an inconsistency... `itemgetter(*(0,))([(0, 0)])` returns a tuple of tuples, but `itemgetter(*(0,))([(0,)])` returns just the tuple...

Comment: Also, +1, but interestingly this didn't end up actually being faster in my original code (in fact it was a little slower).

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm getting a tuple returned by both of the above.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: But are both of them tuples of tuples?

Comment: @Mehrdad No, I'm getting `(0,0)` and `(0,)`, respectively.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, it's because I typo'd. I meant `itemgetter(*(0,))([(0,)])` and `itemgetter(*(0,0))([(0,)])`.

Answer (score 3):

Write a cython function:

```
import cython
from cpython cimport PyList_New, PyList_SET_ITEM, Py_INCREF

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def take(list alist, Py_ssize_t[:] arr):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, idx, n = arr.shape[0]
        list res = PyList_New(n)
        object obj

    for i in range(n):
        idx = arr[i]
        obj = alist[idx]
        PyList_SET_ITEM(res, i, alist[idx])
        Py_INCREF(obj)

    return res
```

The result of %timeit:

```
import numpy as np

al= list(range(10000))
aa = np.array(al)

ba = np.random.randint(0, len(a), 10000)
bl = ba.tolist()

%timeit [al[i] for i in bl]
%timeit np.take(aa, ba)
%timeit take(al, ba)

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.4 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 254 µs per loop
```

`numpy.take()` is the fastest if both of the arguments are ndarray object. The cython version is 5x faster than list comprehension.

Comment: Nice.  Now I wonder why my Numba attempts were so slow.  If you know Numba can you try to make a Numba function that's faster than the list comprehension?  I couldn't.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, numba make a copy of the list internal : http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#list